# Replace NA values with 999 in R subsetted by ID

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have created the following dataframe in R

```
    df<-data.frame("ID"=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),"II"=c(NA, NA, 
    NA,1,2,3),"JJ"=c(1,2,3, NA, NA, NA), 'KK'=c(1,2,NA, NA, 5,6))
```

The dataframe generated is as follows

```
  ID II JJ KK
   A NA  1  1
   A NA  2  2
   A NA  3 NA
   B  1 NA NA
   B  2 NA  5
   B  3 NA  6
```

I want to subset the dataframe by the ID values and replace all columns that contain only NA values with 999. the result should be as folows

```
 ID  II  JJ KK
  A 999   1  1
  A 999   2  2
  A 999   3 NA
  B   1 999 NA
  B   2 999  5
  B   3 999  6
```

I have tried this code

```
   library(dplyr)
   df%>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   select(II, JJ,KK)%>%
   mutate_if(df[, colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df)]<999)
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Adding missing grouping variables: `ID`
 Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .p, .env, ..., .include_group_vars = 
 .include_group_vars) : 
 length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is not TRUE
```

I request someone to take a look. I am unable to figure it out. Not essential for dplyr based solution

Comment: Not a duplicate of @tifu recommendation

Comment: You are right, will be deleting the recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To chip in a `data.table` solution as well:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, 
            function(col) if (all(is.na(col))) 999 else col), 
     by = ID]
#    ID  II  JJ KK
# 1:  A 999   1  1
# 2:  A 999   2  2
# 3:  A 999   3 NA
# 4:  B   1 999 NA
# 5:  B   2 999  5
# 6:  B   3 999  6
```

We loop through all non `ID` columns with `lapply` and replace them by `999` if all of the are `NA`.

Comment: You could use `setDT()` instead of `as.data.table()` (this is faster) AND you don't need to specify `.SDcols` --- it is automatically all the columns not specified in `by`.

Comment: Thanks, I am just learning `data.table` (I am more of a `dplyr` guy) - will change the code, thanks for your insight, very helpfull! +1

Answer (score 10):

We can use `all` to capture groups with all NAs. Since we want to replace the `NA`s in all columns, then we can use `mutate_all`, where the `funs` (i.e. function to be applied to all the columns) is a simple `replace()` of the groups where `all()` values are NA. The replacement is `999`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(., all(is.na(.)), 999)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>   ID       II    JJ    KK
>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 A       999     1     1
> 2 A       999     2     2
> 3 A       999     3    NA
> 4 B         1   999    NA
> 5 B         2   999     5
> 6 B         3   999     6
> ```

Comment: Neat. May I ask how it works sir. I am clear upto group_by but from mutate_all am a bit unclear

Comment: @marciaakshayaLeo I added an explanation. Let me know If you have any other questions

Answer (score 1):

And a base r approach:

```
df[sapply(df, function(x)
  if(is.numeric(x)) is.na(ave(x, df$ID, FUN = function(y)
    mean(y, na.rm = TRUE))) else rep(FALSE, length(x)))] <- 999

df
  ID  II  JJ KK
1  A 999   1  1
2  A 999   2  2
3  A 999   3 NA
4  B   1 999 NA
5  B   2 999  5
6  B   3 999  6
```